# Code for Updating the Master Page Powershell 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell, master-page

Can someone please walkthrough this code for me. I just want to make sure that I understand it correctly. I've gotten it to run, but nothing seems to be happenings.

Basically, I just need to know what components the CustomMasterUrl is pointing to, also the MasterUrl. Are these the locations of the page that you are trying to upload?

For publishing sites and non publishing sites

```
$site = Get-SPSite server
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
$web; $web.CustomMasterUrl = "_catalogs/masterpage/V4.master"; 
$web.Update(); $web.CustomMasterUrl;
$web.Dispose()
}
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
$web; $web.MasterUrl = "_catalogs/masterpage/V4.master"; 
$web.Update(); $web.MasterUrl;
$web.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
write-host "Complete! V4.master is now applied";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is working for me. It just read parameters, you can uncomment lines for editing.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://localhost/
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    #$web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master";
    #$web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master";
    #$web.Update();
    Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
}
```

Comment: Is the relativeURL the location of the master page which you are trying to update, or is it the new one that you are trying to load? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand you. I upload my custom masterpage to server via web interface or SPD and then I activate the masterpage with this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can update Master page of any site using powershell by using following code

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://sp:2000/sites/Ex15
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  &quot;/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master&quot;;
    $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + &quot;/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master&quot;;
    $web.Update();
    Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
}
$site.Dispose()

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    #Get All site collections
    $SiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All
    #Loop through all site collections
       foreach($Site in $SiteCollections)
        {
            #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
           foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
           {
        $web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  &quot;/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master&quot;;
        $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + &quot;/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master&quot;;
        $web.Update();
        Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
           }
        }
```

Full code and description found on this blog [CodePlayAndLearn](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/update-master-page-of-sharepointsite-using-powershell/)